# The probability to win in a promotional quiz

Tags: probability

In a promotional quiz each player, independently, has the chance of winning 1 000 Euros with probability p. It is obviously bad for the organizer if more than one person wins, but it is also considered bad for the promotion if nobody wins at all.

---

(a) With 500 players participating, what is the optimal choice for p, i.e. the one that
maximizes the chance of exactly one player winning?

---

(b) For this value of p, what is the expected payout?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware that the chance of there being exactly one winner is $n\cdot p\cdot(1-p)^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that exact $1$ player wins , is

$$500p(1-p)^{499}$$

The maximum of this function is at $p=\frac{1}{500}$, so this is the best
choice of the probability. In this case, the expected payout is $2$ Euros
for each participant, so $1000$ Euros in total.

Comment: It is straigh-forward to calculate the derivate and consider the values $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Since the roots of the derivate are $1$ and $\frac{1}{500}$, the maximum must be at $\frac{1}{500}$, which can be approved by considering the second derivate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For your first question, you need to see, if you want one person to win, you have to take $p$, and the others have to lose, so they have to take $1-p$. In that case, for $500$ players, you get: $500*p*(1-p)^{499}$. You need to take the best $p$ to make this product as high as possible.

Comment: so, to find the best p, I  need to take the derivative.

Comment: Correct, I misread the question :)

Comment: Yeah, you could try to derivate by $p$ and find the maximum.

Comment: I see, thankyou

Comment: Someone above already solved the question, this was just a hint. :)